# Multiple Views in a Single Column

Tags: android, view, tablelayout

Does anyone know a way to handle multiple views in a single column?  I've been trying something where I have a table row with one column as another tablelayout with 3 textviews but the views won't fit into the screen until I use the wide layout on the screen by turning it sideways.

```
        <TableRow>

        <TextView
            style="@style/strings"
            android:text="Initial Date" />

        <TableLayout>

            <TableRow>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/ckMonth"
                    android:inputType="number" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/ckDay"
                    android:inputType="number" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/ckYear"
                    android:inputType="number" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I known , TableLayout's subcontrols cannt set the `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

attributes ,they will be forced to accept the `fill_parent`

So I think you cannt put multiple views in one column.

But , I think you can use the `android:layout_span` instead.

Comment: Thanks!  I will try this when I get home today.